# Condition in SQL Server computed column

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, calculated-columns

I've created a table in SQL Server which stores batsman run and ball-faced count, in addition to it I had a computed column to get players strike rate

```
(((100) * [TotalRun]) / [TotalBallPlayed])
```

it works fine unless the first ball becomes invalid and player scores run against it.

For example:

- TotalRun = 2
- TotalBallPlayed = 0 (as ball was no ball)

Then this computed column creates an exception which results in an error in the program.

Is there any way to add a condition in the computed column to avoid that situation?

Comment: you can not use any condition into computed column, but you can put condition using trigger on table.

Comment: please refer this link : https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/04/27/sql-server-computed-column-conditions-case-statement/

Comment: @RonakPatel: sure you can use a condition - like an `IIF` - see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an `IIF` condition like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableNameHere
ADD StrikeRate AS IIF(TotalBallPlayed > 0, (100.0 * [TotalRun]) / [TotalBallPlayed], 0);
```

This will return the formula you had if `TotalBallPlayed` is larger than zero, or just `0`, if `TotalBallPlayed = 0`

Comment: thanks! i used nullif condition and its working as well!

Comment: @T.Giri: if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.